# Производитель товара на странице списка товаров

Tags: opencart

Как сделать так чтобы, чтобы в каталоге, где выставлены товары принадлежащие данному каталогу (не страница товара, карточки товара) показывались производители товаров, между названием и описанием товара?

[image: отмечено место, где бы хотелось представить производителя]

на странице товара, например указан производитель

[image: на странице товара, например указан производитель]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле `catalog/controller/product/category.php` найди срочку

```
$data['products'][] = array(
```

затем добавь в массив

```
'rating' => $result['rating'],
'manufacturer' => $result['manufacturer'], // <= это нужно добавить
```

Изначально в классе (модель) `ModelCatalogProduct` статический метод `getProducts()` не получает данные по manufacturer из БД. Нужно это исправить.

Отредактируй в файле
`catalog/model/catalog/product.php` метод `getProducts()`

в `SELECT` запроса добавить

```
m.name as manufacturer
```

и дополнительно в запросе прописать связь с manufacturer

```
LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m ON p.manufacturer_id = m.manufacturer_id
```

Затем в шаблоне `category.tpl` выведи производителя (внутри итератора foreach)

```
<?php echo $product['manufacturer']; ?>
```

Comment: честно говоря я не програмист. Если сможете, пожалуйста пошагово. этой строчки $this->data['products'][] = array( я вообще не нашёл. Честно говоря и  $this->data  этой части не найду. Если можно могу отправить файл.

Comment: `$this->data` поправил и заменил на `$data`.  Находится тут: https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/product/category.php#L213

Comment: На мой взгляд описание не нуждается в дополнительном разъяснении и содержит информацию с последовательными действиями которые необходимо выполнить. Если у вас возникают трудности, наймите специалиста.

Answer (score 0):

**Opencart 3. Добовляем товару производителя с активной ссылкой**

Вывести производителя.фаил - *\catalog\controller\product\category.php*, масив - **$data['products'][] = array**( сюда... );  добавить код ниже

```
'manufacturer'   => $result['manufacturer'],
'manufacturers'  => $this->url->link('product/manufacturer/info', 'manufacturer_id=' . $result['manufacturer_id']),
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ссылка на производителя. файл - *product\category.twig*  добавить

```
{% if product.manufacturer %}
{{ text_manufacturer }} <a href="{{ product.manufacturers }}">{{ product.manufacturer }}</a>
{% endif %}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]